# awk - deleted a field but can't get rid of it's delimiter

Tags: awk

My input file consists of lines of csv where col 1 is the file name and the rest of the line is to output verbatim to the file whose name is given in col 1.

Example input.

```
file1,field1, field2, field3
file2,field4,field5,field6
```

and I want `file1` to contain:

```
field1,field2,field3
```

and `file2` to contain:

```
field4,field5,field6
```

But I am getting a leading comma as the first character of each line.

I set OFS and FS to ',' on the command line then my code is

```
{
  fn = "dummy/" $1 ".txt" 
  $1 = ""
  print $0 > fn 
}
```

Only problem is that I get a leading comma output to each file which is obviously the place holder for the first field was deleted.

Looking for an explanation with your awk solution.

Comment: You can do `cat file1 | cut -d "," -f 2- >tmp_file && mv tmp_file file1` btw

Comment: If all of your lines are four fields in total, you can `print $2, $3, $4` instead of setting `$1` to `''` and printing `$0`.

Comment: You show the output missing the leading spaces from ```…, field2, field3``` — is that intentional, or just a quirk of editing material into the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{close(out); out="dummy/"$1".txt"; sub(/[^,]*,/,""); print >> out}' file
```

Note that the above will append to any pre-existing output files so zap them first if that's an issue or tweak it to do the job itself:

```
awk '{close(out); out="dummy/"$1".txt"; sub(/[^,]*,/,""); if (seen[out]++) print >> out; else print > out}' file
```

or if there's only 1 line per output file name then all you need is:

```
awk '{close(out); out="dummy/"$1".txt"; sub(/[^,]*,/,""); print > out}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

with awk, there is another trick you can do:

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)$i=$(i+1);NF--}7' <<<'0,1,2,3'
1,2,3
```

(the file redirection part was ignored, since apparently you know how does it work)

Comment: That is awesome. Added to my answer.

Comment: The effect of decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX so it'll do what you want in gawk, for example, but won't in other awks.

Comment: @EdMorton everytime I read your answer/comment, I learn from your deep knowledge about shell/awk/sed... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file{1,2}
file1,field1,field2,field3
file2,field4,field5,field6
```

You can use `cut` and a Bash loop:

```
for fn in file{1,2}; do
    cut -d "," -f 2- "$fn" >tmp_file && mv tmp_file "$fn"
done  

$ cat file{1,2}
field1,field2,field3
field4,field5,field6
```

For the `awk` to do this, the classic idiom is to to do:

```
awk '{$1=""}1' input | awk '{$1=$1}1' > output
```

But THAT won't work. I suppose you can do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{fn=$1; $1=""; print substr($0,2,length($0)-1)>fn}' file{1,2}
```

Then:

```
cat file{1,2}
field1,field2,field3
field4,field5,field6
```

I am concerned that that will not work with files larger than a single line since awk was not designed to write to the file it is reading from.

---

With `gawk` it is all a lot easier since `gawk` supports [in place file editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)

So you can do it the idiomatic way and not worry about overwriting the input file with the output:

```
gawk -F, -v OFS=, -i inplace '{$1="";print substr($0,2,length($0)-1)}' file{1,2}
```

Which also works great with [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent)'s [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218605/15168):

```
gawk -F, -v OFS=, -i inplace '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)$i=$(i+1);NF--}1' file{1,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

without normalizing the fields (spaces around delimiters)

```
$ awk -F, '{file=$1; sub($1 FS,""); print > file}' file

$ head file?
==> file1 <==
field1, field2, field3

==> file2 <==
field4,field5,field6
```

Comment: That approach will fail when $1 or FS contain RE metacharacters and will fail in non-GNU awks when there's many output file names.